# Why doesn't command redirection operator work in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, io-redirection

I want to run a python script in PyCharm and redirect the stdin out put to a file. Therefore, I opened Run/Debug configurations and typed:

```
>> output.txt
```

in script parameters field. When I run the script, I get the error:

> error: unrecognized arguments: >> output.txt

Do you know how to use redirection operator in PyCharm environment?

Comment: idk about pycharm but just doing `sys.stdout = open("output.txt","w")` would redirect output to your file, I **do not** recommend this in production code though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

It is available in Run -->EditConfigurations.

On the right side you will have Logs tab which says Save console output to file.

You may use that option.

Comment: Correct. 
Run -> Edit Configurations -> Logs -> Save console output to file: ....